# Date Not display in proper Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, model

```
<b>View Code</b><br><br>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.start_date, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", new { onclick = "javascript:NewCssCal( this.Id,'ddMMMyyyy','arrow','','','','future')" })
```

when return Model from the controller if start_date is null or empty it shows default date in textbox like **"01-Jan-0001"** . I just show Textbox field blank.what will i do.

i was try many solution from net but not get any proper solution

eg, changes in model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}",
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

**Expected Result** 
1. if model start_date is blank then it show blank textbox not to show default value like  "01-Jan-0001".
2. if model start_date field contain value then show that value for eg. 23-Mar-2019

Comment: Please give the Answer not edit

Comment: What keeps you from adding an `@if ...` for the `start_date` property and then putting out the value you need? I mean you basically put the answer in the _Expected Result_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the model you can make the property nullable by adding a '?' behind the type

```
public Date? start_date { get; set; }
```